# Which feature values correlate with a negative metric

Tags: statistics

I have a data set with categorical values (like region, device type etc.) and a numeric metric value. Something like this (except my data set has many more unique values and categorical columns).

| Region | Device | Metric Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | Laptop | 5 |
| US | PC | 10 |
| Japan | Laptop | 5 |
| Japan | PC | 10 |
| Australia | Laptop | 5 |
| Australia | PC | 1 |

What is the right stats model to figure out which variables (i.e. `Australia` and `PC` would rank high and `Laptop` would rank medium) are effecting the negative metric value?

Thank in you in advance.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question.

Comment: Interesting, however, more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com.